# Powershell script to copy files with approximately same name from folder to another folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have the following situation after receiving close to 130000 xml files representing invoices.

The invoices are in folder and subfolders, based on their creation dates:

Folder 2016, with subfolders: 2016-01-01 (then this subfolders contains xml files), 2016-01-02 (then this other subfolders contains the xml files of the invoices from that day) and so on... until 2016-12-31 (with this subfolder containing the xml files of the invoices from that day)
Folder 2017, with subfolders: 2017-01-01 (then this subfolders contains xml files), 2017-01-02 (then this other subfolders contains the xml files of the invoices from that day) and so on... until 2017-12-31 (with this subfolder containing the xml files of the invoices from that day)
and so on..

The attachments, however, are in a different folder and are all piled in together. They can be either PDFs, either docx, or maybe even PNGs. The only link between the invoice and the attachment is the filename. The invoice is 32 character long: 0bad5e493aa44982bc60d7ed0670465e, and the attachment looks like this: 0bad5e493aa44982bc60d7ed0670465e-1. Most invoices have just one attachment, but others have more, and they look like this: 0bad5e493aa44982bc60d7ed0670465e-2, 0bad5e493aa44982bc60d7ed0670465e-3, 0bad5e493aa44982bc60d7ed0670465e-4.

What I would need is a script that moves the attachments in the correct folders, next to their respective  invoices.

Each already existing folder would contain, after the script runs, the invoices of that day and the attachment(s) of that invoice:

folder 2016 > subfolder 2016-01-01, will contain invoice xml 0bad5e493aa44982bc60d7ed0670465e, and the attachments: 0bad5e493aa44982bc60d7ed0670465e-1, 0bad5e493aa44982bc60d7ed0670465e-2, 0bad5e493aa44982bc60d7ed0670465e-3, and possible other invoices and their respective attachments.

Please point me in the right direction (I was thinking through powershell, but I can try anything else) as this request came in totally unexpected for me and to manually do it it is going to take a lifetime, and I am not much of programmer.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try your look on superuser. This is a bit too vague for SO.

Comment: Start by getting a list of XML files. Use `.BaseName` property to access its name without extension, add `*` to get a wildcard version of the same name and use that one to get a list of matching file names from another a dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Invoices\2016 -Include *.xml -Recurse | Select BaseName, DirectoryName | 
   ForEach { Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Attachments -Include "$($_.BaseName)*.*" -Recurse | 
      Move-Item -Destination $_.DirectoryName }
```

I hope this is want you expect, because I am not sure of your explanations.
Just replace `C:\Invoices\2016` and `C:\Attachments` by the right paths

Comment: Please try to refrain from answering code request type questions; those are off topic on StackOverflow.